# I want to imputation of missing value in data frame which have many attributes how about loop if library(Hmisc) used in R?

Tags: r, attributes, hmisc

My code is:

```
    df <- read.csv("data")
    summary(df)

    library(Hmisc)
    imp_a <- impute(df$a, mean)
    df$a <- imp_a
    imp_b <- impute(df$b, mean)
    df$b <- imp_b
```

If attribute not only a and b how too loop 1000 attributes? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data as simple as this (but with more columns)...

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,NA), b = c(1,NA,2), c = c(NA,2,1))
```

...you can run `mutate_all` from the `dplyr`-package to apply Hmisc's mean imputation to all columns:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_all(.funs = ~Hmisc::impute(.,mean))

    a   b   c
1 0.0 1.0 1.5
2 1.0 1.5 2.0
3 0.5 2.0 1.0
```

If there are columns you don't want to or cannot impute (e.g. character columns), you'd have to slightly adjust the code and probably switch to `mutate_at`, e.g.

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(a:c),
            .funs = ~Hmisc::impute(.,mean))
```

Comment: Thank you @tifu for your answer. but if data frame have many different data type. how about it?    example: a, b, c are int. and d, e are string

Comment: I am not clear what you mean. If you showed us a snippet of your real data, e.g. via `dput (df)`, it would be much easier to help you